# How to create dynamically a Pull Request using SharpBucket (on basic authentication)

Tags: c#, bitbucket, basic-authentication, pull-request

My goal is to create a WPF application to perform a "bitbucket project manager".

I discover [SharpBucket](https://github.com/MitjaBezensek/SharpBucket) but I'm not quite sure how to use it. I'm already able to create a commit on a new branch and push it on remote with [LibGit2Sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp), but now I need the last step of the process: create a Pull Request on Bitbucket for the created branch. Could you please provide me an example?

Last note: I don't have the OAuth/2 bitbucket credentials, so I can access only by basic authentication (bitbucket HTTP access token).

Thanks in advance.